# Error from sklearn.neural_network import MLPRegressor

Tags: python, scikit-learn, neural-network, sklearn-pandas

I am building a Neural Network Code on Python. When I executed the code on my laptop, everything was smooth. When I sent it to my friend: it gave the error shown in the picture. I tried uninstalling python and reinstalling it, unistalling pip, uninstalling sklearn, and then installing them. Nothing worked.

> ImportError:DLL load failed.

Can anyone please help ?

The complete error is the following:

```
RESTART: C:\D-drive\AUB 2019-2020\Fall\CHEN499\Mohamad Ibrahim\499 research\neural networks\example 6\NN1.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\D-drive\AUB 2019-2020\Fall\CHEN499\Mohamad Ibrahim\499 research\neural networks\example 6\NN1.py", line 1, in <module>
    from sklearn.neural_network import MLPRegressor
  File "C:\Users\jz08\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\sklearn\__init__.py", line 75, in <module>
    from .utils._show_versions import show_versions
  File "C:\Users\jz08\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\_show_versions.py", line 12, in <module>
    from ._openmp_helpers import _openmp_parallelism_enabled
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Thank you.[image]

Comment: I also tried uninstalling scipy and numpy and then installing them from the command prompt; but the error is still there...

Comment: Read this: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/10033

Comment: Dear Makis, I tried everything suggested on stackoverflow..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and resolved it only through getting back to one of the previous versions of scikit-learn (0.20.2) Try downgrading sklearn.
I'm aware that this is a sub-optimal solution, but hopefully, you'll be able to advance in whatever project you are currently working one. Hope this helps !

Comment: Looking your specific error up yielded this:
https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/15786
It seems there's an incompatibility between some versions of sklearn and some versions of Visual Studio. The guy solved the problem by installing Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: The solution provided by Mano worked ! Thanks a lot !